# Class to wrap Netapi32.dll functions

Tags: c#, networking, winapi

I have made a class for some Netapi32.dll functions in C#. I would like to know if there are any big problems with it or if there is some other function needed in general.

Functions:

- `NetFileEnum`
- `NetShareEnum`
- `NetFileClose`
- `NetSessionEnum`
- `NetApiBufferFree`

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ph03n1x
{
    public class NetAPI32
    {

        #region Constants
        protected const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;
        #endregion

        #region StructLayout
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct FILE_INFO_3
        {
            public int fi3_id;
            public int fi3_permission;
            public int fi3_num_locks;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string fi3_pathname;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string fi3_username;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SESSION_INFO_502
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Unicode string specifying the name of the computer that established the session.
            /// </summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string si502_cname;

            /// <summary>
            /// <value>Unicode string specifying the name of the user who established the session.</value>
            /// </summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string si502_username;

            /// <summary>
            /// <value>Specifies the number of files, devices, and pipes opened during the session.</value>
            /// </summary>
            public uint si502_num_opens;

            /// <summary>
            /// <value>Specifies the number of seconds the session has been active. </value>
            /// </summary>
            public uint si502_time;

            /// <summary>
            /// <value>Specifies the number of seconds the session has been idle.</value>
            /// </summary>
            public uint si502_idle_time;

            /// <summary>
            /// <value>Specifies a value that describes how the user established the session.</value>
            /// </summary>
            public uint si502_user_flags;

            /// <summary>
            /// <value>Unicode string that specifies the type of client that established the session.</value>
            /// </summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string si502_cltype_name;

            /// <summary>
            /// <value>Specifies the name of the transport that the client is using to communicate with the server.</value>
            /// </summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string si502_transport;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct SHARE_INFO_2
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string NetName;
            public int ShareType;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string Remark;
            public int Permissions;
            public int MaxUsers;
            public int CurrentUsers;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string Path;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string Password;
        }

        #endregion StructLayout

        #region enum
        public enum NERR
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Operation was a success.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_Success = 0,

            /// <summary>
            /// More data available to read. dderror getting all data.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234,

            /// <summary>
            /// Network browsers not available.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_NO_BROWSER_SERVERS_FOUND = 6118,

            /// <summary>
            /// LEVEL specified is not valid for this call.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL = 124,

            /// <summary>
            /// Security context does not have permission to make this call.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5,

            /// <summary>
            /// Parameter was incorrect.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87,

            /// <summary>
            /// Out of memory.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY = 8,

            /// <summary>
            /// Unable to contact resource. Connection timed out.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_NETWORK_BUSY = 54,

            /// <summary>
            /// Network Path not found.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_BAD_NETPATH = 53,

            /// <summary>
            /// No available network connection to make call.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_NO_NETWORK = 1222,

            /// <summary>
            /// Pointer is not valid.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE_STATE = 1609,

            /// <summary>
            /// Extended Error.
            /// </summary>
            ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR = 1208,

            /// <summary>
            /// Base.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_BASE = 2100,

            /// <summary>
            /// Unknown Directory.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_UnknownDevDir = (NERR_BASE + 16),

            /// <summary>
            /// Duplicate Share already exists on server.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_DuplicateShare = (NERR_BASE + 18),

            /// <summary>
            /// Memory allocation was to small.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_BufTooSmall = (NERR_BASE + 23)
        }

        public enum NET_API_STATUS : uint
        {
            NERR_Success = 0,

            /// <summary>
            /// This computer name is invalid.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_InvalidComputer = 2351,

            /// <summary>
            /// This operation is only allowed on the primary domain controller of the domain.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_NotPrimary = 2226,

            /// <summary>
            /// This operation is not allowed on this special group.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_SpeGroupOp = 2234,

            /// <summary>
            /// This operation is not allowed on the last administrative account.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_LastAdmin = 2452,

            /// <summary>
            /// The password parameter is invalid.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_BadPassword = 2203,

            /// <summary>
            /// The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_PasswordTooShort = 2245,

            /// <summary>
            /// The user name could not be found.
            /// </summary>
            NERR_UserNotFound = 2221,

            ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5,
            ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY = 8,
            ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87,
            ERROR_INVALID_NAME = 123,
            ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL = 124,
            ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234,
            ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT = 1219
        }
        #endregion enum

        #region DllImports

        #region NetFileEnum
        [DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int NetFileEnum(
            string servername,
            string basepath,
            string username,
            int level,
            ref IntPtr bufptr,
            int prefmaxlen,
            out int entriesread,
            out int totalentries,
            IntPtr resume_handle
            );
        #endregion NetFileEnum

        #region NetShareEnum
        [DllImport("netapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        protected static extern int NetShareEnum(
            string lpServerName,
            int dwLevel,
            out IntPtr lpBuffer,
            int dwPrefMaxLen,
            out int entriesRead,
            out int totalEntries,
            ref int hResume
            );
        #endregion NetShareEnum

        #region NetFileClose
        [DllImport("Netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int NetFileClose(string servername, int id);
        #endregion NetFileClose

        #region NetSessionEnum
        [DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int NetSessionEnum
            (
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ServerName,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string UncClientName,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string UserName,
            Int32 Level,
            out IntPtr bufptr,
            int prefmaxlen,
            ref Int32 entriesread,
            ref Int32 totalentries,
            ref Int32 resume_handle
            );
        #endregion NetSessionEnum

        #region NetApiBufferFree
        [DllImport("Netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);
        #endregion NetApiBufferFree

        #endregion DllImports

        #region myMethods
        public static List<SESSION_INFO_502> BuildNetSessionEnumList(string server)
        {
            List<SESSION_INFO_502> list = new List<SESSION_INFO_502>();

            IntPtr BufPtr;
            int res = 0;
            Int32 er = 0, tr = 0, resume = 0;
            SESSION_INFO_502[] results = new SESSION_INFO_502[0];
            res = NetSessionEnum(null, null, null, 502, out BufPtr, -1, ref er, ref tr, ref resume);
            results = new SESSION_INFO_502[er];
            if (res == (int)NERR.ERROR_MORE_DATA || res == (int)NERR.NERR_Success)
            {
                Int32 p = BufPtr.ToInt32();
                for (int i = 0; i < er; i++)
                {

                    SESSION_INFO_502 si = (SESSION_INFO_502)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(p), typeof(SESSION_INFO_502));
                    results[i] = si;
                    p += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SESSION_INFO_502));

                    list.Add(si);
                }
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(BufPtr);

            return list;

        }
        public static List<FILE_INFO_3> BuildNetFileEnumList(string server)
        {
            List<FILE_INFO_3> list = new List<FILE_INFO_3>();

            const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;
            int dwReadEntries;
            int dwTotalEntries;
            IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            FILE_INFO_3 pCurrent = new FILE_INFO_3();

            int dwStatus = NetFileEnum(server, null, null, 3, ref pBuffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out dwReadEntries,
                out dwTotalEntries, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (dwStatus == 0)
            {
                for (int dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < dwReadEntries; dwIndex++)
                {

                    IntPtr iPtr = new IntPtr(pBuffer.ToInt32() + (dwIndex * Marshal.SizeOf(pCurrent)));
                    pCurrent = (FILE_INFO_3)Marshal.PtrToStructure(iPtr, typeof(FILE_INFO_3));

                    list.Add(pCurrent);
                }
                NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);
            }
            return list;
        }
        public static List<SHARE_INFO_2> BuildNetShareEnumList(string server)
        {
            //Note that this code will only work if run as administrator!!

            List<SHARE_INFO_2> list = new List<SHARE_INFO_2>();
            int entriesRead, totalEntries, nRet, hResume = 0;
            IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;

            nRet = NetShareEnum(server, 2, out pBuffer, -1,
                    out entriesRead, out totalEntries, ref hResume);

            if (entriesRead > 0)
            {
                Type t = typeof(SHARE_INFO_2);
                int offset = Marshal.SizeOf(t);

                for (int i = 0, lpItem = pBuffer.ToInt32(); i < entriesRead; i++, lpItem += offset)
                {
                    IntPtr pItem = new IntPtr(lpItem);

                    SHARE_INFO_2 si = (SHARE_INFO_2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pItem, t);
                    list.Add(si);
                }
            }
            NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);

            return list;
        }

        #endregion myMethods
    }
}
```

Here is some samples on how to use them:

```
    List<NetAPI32.SHARE_INFO_2> shares = NetAPI32.BuildNetShareEnumList(null);
    foreach (NetAPI32.SHARE_INFO_2 share in shares)
    {
        int maxAllowedUsers = share.MaxUsers;
        int shareType = share.ShareType;
        string shareName = share.NetName;
        string sharePath = share.Path;
        string shareRemark = share.Remark;
        int currentConectedUsers = share.CurrentUsers;
    }

    List<NetAPI32.FILE_INFO_3> fileconnections = NetAPI32.BuildNetFileEnumList(null);
    foreach (NetAPI32.FILE_INFO_3 fileconnection in fileconnections)
    {
        int remoteUserPrimition = fileconnection.fi3_permission;
        string remoteUsername = fileconnection.fi3_username;
        string sharePath = fileconnection.fi3_pathname;
        int shareID = fileconnection.fi3_id;
    }

    List<NetAPI32.SESSION_INFO_502> connectionsInfo = NetAPI32.BuildNetSessionEnumList(null);
    foreach (NetAPI32.SESSION_INFO_502 connectionInfo in connectionsInfo)
    {
        string remoteUsername = connectionInfo.si502_username;
        string remoteIP = connectionInfo.si502_cname;
        int conectionTime = Convert.ToInt32(connectionInfo.si502_time);
        int fileOpenCount = Convert.ToInt32(connectionInfo.si502_num_opens);
    }
```

Most of the code is a Frankenstein's monster of code googled.

Answer (score 3):

**BuildNetSessionEnumList()**

- Declaring multiple variables on the same line reduces readability.
- You don't really use the `SESSION_INFO_502[] results` array and you can safely remove it.

---

**Naming**

- You have `SHARE_INFO_2 si` and `FILE_INFO_3 pCurrent`.
- Local variables should be named using `camelCase` casing. See [the .NET style guide.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678178/style-guide-for-c)
- You should avoid shortening variable names; that reduces readability.
- Using `list` for the name of each requested `List<T>` also reduces readability.
- Other places that have a .NET implementation of `NetSessionEnum`, e.g. the [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) signature, have well-named parameters. Why doesn't your code use those names when calling this method? You name them `res`, `er`, `tr = 0`, and `resume` which doesn't communicate anything about them.

---

You should declare variables as near as possible to their usage. In the `BuildNetFileEnumList()` method you are declaring `FILE_INFO_3 pCurrent = new FILE_INFO_3();` at the top but need it only inside of the loop.
Additionally, there's no need to use `new` at that point, since later in the loop you are assigning a new value to it.

---

You should be consistent in the style you use.

In the `BuildNetSessionEnumList()` method you are incrementing the pointer like

> ```
>     Int32 p = BufPtr.ToInt32();
>     for (int i = 0; i < er; i++)
>     {
>
>         SESSION_INFO_502 si = (SESSION_INFO_502)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(p), typeof(SESSION_INFO_502));
>         p += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SESSION_INFO_502));
>
>         list.Add(si);
>     }
> ```

and in the `BuildNetFileEnumList()` method like

> ```
>     for (int dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < dwReadEntries; dwIndex++)
>     {
>
>         IntPtr iPtr = new IntPtr(pBuffer.ToInt32() + (dwIndex * Marshal.SizeOf(pCurrent)));
>         pCurrent = (FILE_INFO_3)Marshal.PtrToStructure(iPtr, typeof(FILE_INFO_3));
>
>         list.Add(pCurrent);
>     }
> ```

and in the `BuildNetShareEnumList()` method you are using a third way

> ```
>     Type t = typeof(SHARE_INFO_2);
>     int offset = Marshal.SizeOf(t);
>
>     for (int i = 0, lpItem = pBuffer.ToInt32(); i < entriesRead; i++, lpItem += offset)
>     {
>         IntPtr pItem = new IntPtr(lpItem);
>
>         SHARE_INFO_2 si = (SHARE_INFO_2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pItem, t);
>         list.Add(si);
>     }
> ```

---

You have declared a `protected const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;` at class level and then again inside the `BuildNetFileEnumList()` method `const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into fixing "Frankenstein's monster" feel to it then updating this post with the results.

Comment: Don't update the post, see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice !! i have updated the code somewhat...

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing you have a very good detailed answer, and you've already updated your code as answer as well.  The new code looks a lot cleaner but both the old code and new code - particularly your *build* methods - require a server parameter.  Just one example of the many:

Old Code:

```
public static List<SESSION_INFO_502> BuildNetSessionEnumList(string server)
```

New Code:

```
public static List<SessionInfo502> BuildNetSessionEnumList(string server)
```

Since the parameter is not optional, the code to use it looks kind of clunky:

```
List<NetAPI32.SessionInfo502> connectionsInfo = NetAPI32.BuildNetSessionEnumList(null);
```

This can be cleaned up by making the parameter optional in the signature, and also by using `var` when using it.  Example:

Definition:

```
public static List<SessionInfo502> BuildNetSessionEnumList(string server = null)
```

Usage Example:

```
var connectionsInfo = NetAPI32.BuildNetSessionEnumList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of time today to work on this, im still not sure if everything is 100% but here is update. Mainly i took out a lot of unnecessary/redundant/confusing code and made things uniform/readable. I may have broken something along the way so please review again. I tried to follow Heslacher's guidelines, and added some extra functions.

Functions:

```
NetFileEnum
NetShareEnum
NetSessionDel
NetShareDel
NetSessionEnum
NetApiBufferFree
```

Here is the class again:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ph03n1x
{
    public class NetAPI32
    {
        #region StructLayout
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct FileInfo3
        {
            public int SessionID;
            public int Permission;
            public int NumLocks;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string PathName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string UserName;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SessionInfo502
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string ComputerName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string UserName;
            public uint NumOpens;
            public uint SecondsActive;
            public uint SecondsIdle;
            public uint UserFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string ClientType;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string Transport;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct ShareInfo2
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string NetName;
            public int ShareType;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string Remark;
            public int Permissions;
            public int MaxUsers;
            public int CurrentUsers;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string Path;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string Password;
        }

        #endregion StructLayout

        #region DllImports

        #region NetFileEnum
        [DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int NetFileEnum(
            string serverName,
            string basePath,
            string userName,
            int level,
            ref IntPtr buffer,
            int prefMaxLength,
            out int entriesRead,
            out int totalEntries,
            ref int resumeHandle
            );
        #endregion NetFileEnum

        #region NetShareEnum
        [DllImport("netapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        protected static extern int NetShareEnum(
            string serverName,
            int level,
            out IntPtr buffer,
            int prefMaxLength,
            out int entriesRead,
            out int totalEntries,
            ref int resumeHandle
            );
        #endregion NetShareEnum

        #region NetSessionDel
        [DllImport("NetApi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern uint NetSessionDel(
             string serverName,
             string uncClientName,
             string userName);
        //eg. NetSessionDel(null, null, "USERNAMETODELETE")
        #endregion NetSessionDel

        #region NetShareDel
        [DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint NetShareDel(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
            string serverName,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
            string shareName,
            Int32 reserved //must be 0
                    );
        #endregion NetShareDel

        #region NetSessionEnum
        [DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int NetSessionEnum
            (
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            string serverName,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            string uncClientName,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            string userName,
            Int32 level,
            out IntPtr buffer,
            int prefmaxlen,
            out int entriesRead,
            out int totalEntries,
            ref int resumeHandle
            );
        #endregion NetSessionEnum

        #region NetApiBufferFree
        [DllImport("Netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);
        #endregion NetApiBufferFree

        #endregion DllImports

        #region Methods
        public static List<SessionInfo502> BuildNetSessionEnumList(string server)
        {
            List<SessionInfo502> list = new List<SessionInfo502>();

            int entriesRead;
            int totalEntries;
            int resumeHandle = 0;
            IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            int status = NetSessionEnum(server, null, null, 502, out pBuffer, -1, out entriesRead, out totalEntries, ref resumeHandle);

            if (status == 0 & entriesRead > 0)
            {
                Type shareinfoType = typeof(SessionInfo502);
                int offset = Marshal.SizeOf(shareinfoType);

                for (int i = 0, item = pBuffer.ToInt32(); i < entriesRead; i++, item += offset)
                {
                    IntPtr pItem = new IntPtr(item);

                    SessionInfo502 sessionInfo502 = (SessionInfo502)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pItem, shareinfoType);
                    list.Add(sessionInfo502);
                }
            }
            NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);
            return list;
        }

        public static List<FileInfo3> BuildNetFileEnumList(string server)
        {
            List<FileInfo3> list = new List<FileInfo3>();

            int entriesRead;
            int totalEntries;
            int resumeHandle = 0;
            IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            int status = NetFileEnum(server, null, null, 3, ref pBuffer, -1, out entriesRead, out totalEntries, ref resumeHandle);

            if (status == 0 & entriesRead > 0)
            {
                Type shareinfoType = typeof(FileInfo3);
                int offset = Marshal.SizeOf(shareinfoType);

                for (int i = 0, item = pBuffer.ToInt32(); i < entriesRead; i++, item += offset)
                {
                    IntPtr pItem = new IntPtr(item);

                    FileInfo3 fileInfo3 = (FileInfo3)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pItem, shareinfoType);
                    list.Add(fileInfo3);
                }
                NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);
            }
            return list;
        }

        public static List<ShareInfo2> BuildNetShareEnumList(string server)
        {
            //Note that this code will only work if run as administrator!!
            List<ShareInfo2> list = new List<ShareInfo2>();

            int entriesRead;
            int totalEntries;
            int resumeHandle = 0;
            IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            int status = NetShareEnum(server, 2, out pBuffer, -1, out entriesRead, out totalEntries, ref resumeHandle);

            if (status == 0 & entriesRead > 0)
            {
                Type shareinfoType = typeof(ShareInfo2);
                int offset = Marshal.SizeOf(shareinfoType);

                for (int i = 0, item = pBuffer.ToInt32(); i < entriesRead; i++, item += offset)
                {
                    IntPtr pItem = new IntPtr(item);

                    ShareInfo2 shareInfo2 = (ShareInfo2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pItem, shareinfoType);
                    list.Add(shareInfo2);
                }
            }
            NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);

            return list;
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

And here is some samples on how to use them:

```
List<NetAPI32.ShareInfo2> shares = NetAPI32.BuildNetShareEnumList(null);
foreach (NetAPI32.ShareInfo2 share in shares)
{
    int maxAllowedUsers = share.MaxUsers;
    int shareType = share.ShareType;
    string shareName = share.NetName;
    string sharePath = share.Path;
    string shareRemark = share.Remark;
    int currentConectedUsers = share.CurrentUsers;
}

List<NetAPI32.FileInfo3> fileconnections = NetAPI32.BuildNetFileEnumList(null);
foreach (NetAPI32.FileInfo3 fileconnection in fileconnections)
{
    int remoteUserPrimition = fileconnection.Permission;
    string remoteUsername = fileconnection.UserName;
    string sharePath = fileconnection.PathName;
    int shareID = fileconnection.SessionID;
}

List<NetAPI32.SessionInfo502> connectionsInfo = NetAPI32.BuildNetSessionEnumList(null);
foreach (NetAPI32.SessionInfo502 connectionInfo in connectionsInfo)
{
    string remoteUsername = connectionInfo.UserName;
    string remoteIP = connectionInfo.ComputerName;
    int conectionTime = Convert.ToInt32(connectionInfo.SecondsActive);
    int fileOpenCount = Convert.ToInt32(connectionInfo.NumOpens);
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you want a follow-up review you should post it as a new question (with a link back to this one if you want to provide context), rather than an answer.

Comment: thanks for the advice i just didn't want to keep re-posting this everywhere/ every time i made a update, but if you say so...

Comment: @DarkPh03n1X A review can be an iterative process.  You post a chunk of code and receive many suggestions.  Implement those suggestions in a separate post but note it helps if (1) you use the same title but with a "Version 2" or something on the end, and (2) if you put links in each post to all related posts.  It's not uncommon to see 4 or 5 versions spawned from an original post.

Comment: Ok I will Keep it in mind, i'm going to update the code as soon as i get a chance, then i will create a new toppic